# ¿Consulta con where sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

Tengo un inconveniente con sequelize, necesito obtener las tareas pertenecientes a una subactividad y dicha subactividad pertenece a una actividad general y la actividad general pertenece a un proyecto, el inconveniente es que el **where** no esta funcionando me obtiene todas las tareas de la tabla

```
module.exports.findTareaCompleta = (req, res) => {
   const id_proyecto = req.params.id_proyecto;
   tareas.findAll({include:[{model:subactividades, as: 'subactividades',
             include:[{model:actividades_generales, as: 'actividad_general',where: {id_proyecto}}]}],
             order: [['id_orden', 'ASC']]
   }).then(_tarea => {
    res.status(200).json(_tarea);
   }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(406).json({err: err})
   })
}
```

Comment: Hola, tienes un error en la forma en la que implementas tu cláusula `where`, además, ¿crees que puedes postear tu modelo o un ejemplo de registro? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema lo tienes en la forma que estás usando la cláusula `where`. Debes realizar una comparación, en cambio solo pasas un valor, que Javascript lo interpretará como `true`, es decir lo interpretará como algo parecido al famoso:

```
where 1=1
```

lo cual en consecuencia te trae todos los registros.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla, solo debes pasar el valor adecuado a la cláusula `where`.

Sin entrar en detalles sobre cómo son tus modelos o cuáles las tablas consultadas, voy a mostrarte como debes realizar la consulta. Este tipo de consultas se conocen como `Eager Loading`, ya que la misma buscará realizar las asociaciones necesarias en una sola consulta. Puedes leer un poco más sobre esto en: [Eager loading - Sequelize Model usage](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-usage.html#eager-loading)

Tu consulta debería quedar así:

```
module.exports.findTareaCompleta = (req, res) => {
    const id_proyecto = req.params.id_proyecto;
    tareas.findAll({
        include:[{
            model: subactividades,
            as: 'subactividades',
            include: [{
                model: actividades_generales, as: 'actividad_general',
                where: {id_proyecto: id_proyecto} //<- Aqui debes realizar el cambio
            }]
        }],
        order: [['id_orden', 'ASC']]
    })
    .then(_tarea => {
        res.status(200).json(_tarea);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(406).json({err: err})
    });
}
```

Como puedes ver, el cambio que debes realizar en tu cláusula `where` es:

```
where: {id_proyecto: id_proyecto}
```

Estoy asumiendo que el campo sobre el cual vas a aplicar la cláusula se llama `id_proyecto`.

Espero que esto solucione tu problema.

Comment: Hola @Mauricio Contreras . si tengo un modeloA relacionado con un ModeloB y el modeloB esta relacionado con un modeloC , yo podria hacer un inner join entre el A y el B y luego con este resultado hacer otro inner join con el modelo C ? logré hacer el inner join entre el A y el B usando el include, pero no encuentro como hacer para luego unir ese resultado con el modelo C cuándo con la condición de que 2 de sus columnas sean iguales.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que es conveniente primero traer la informacion del proyecto, actividad y sub-actividad, una vez conociendo sobre cual subactividad esta trabajando puede usar querys dentro de sequelize, asumiendo que **tareas** es el modelo de sequelize y que tiene un foreing-key de subactividad como **IdSubActividad** , una propuesta seria la siguiente:

```
async function encontrarTareasPorSubactividad(res,res) {
    try{
        let idSubActividad = req.params.idsubactividad
        let result = await tareas.sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM TAREAS WHERE 
        "IdSubActividad" = ?  ', { replacements: [parseInt(idSubActividad)], 
        type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
        console.log(result)     
        res.status(200).json(result)       
    }catch (error) {
        res.status(500).jsonp({ message: error.message })
    }}

  module.exports.encontrarTareasPorSubactividad = encontrarTareasPorSubactividad
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que aunque sequelize nos permite trabajar con bases de datos relacionales, hay que tener en cuenta las implicaciones por cada una de ellas, por ejemplo: para postgres en el query seria necesario colocar el parámetro de busqueda dentro de comillas **("IdSubActividad")** para que postgres lo reconozca. Pero como mencione, eso depende del motor con el que este trabajando.